# mailgun.messages is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mailgun

I am trying to get my e-commerce web app to send emails on purchasing but when I try to pay for things I get the mailgun.messages is not a function I've reverted changes and re coded it twice but this is a different error I'm not sure how to resolve this. Is there another way to use mailgun's api?  Here is the code below:
orderRoutes.js:

```
orderRouter.put(
  "/:id/pay",
  isAuth,
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const order = await Order.findById(req.params.id).populate(
      "user",
      "email firstName"
    );
    if (order) {
      order.isPaid = true;
      order.paidAt = Date.now();
      order.paymentResult = {
        id: req.body.id,
        status: req.body.status,
        update_time: req.body.update_time,
        email_address: req.body.email_address,
      };
      const updateOrder = await order.save();
      mailgun.messages().send(
        {
          from: "Sales <sales@cocoTiCosmetics.com>",
          to: `${order.user.firstName} <${order.user.email}>`,
          subject: `New Order ${order._id}`,
          html: payOrderEmailTemplate(order),
        },
        (error, body) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
          } else {
            console.log(body);
          }
        }
      );
      res.send({ message: "Order Paid", order: updateOrder });
    } else {
      res.status(404).send({ message: "Order Not Found" });
    }
  })
);
```

utils.js

```
export const mailgun = () =>
  mg({
    apiKey: process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY,
    domain: process.env.MAILGUN_DOMAIN,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The library `mailgun-js` is no longer supported. You can use the official library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun.js

Please note that this library ends in `.js` rather than `-js`.